# Dynamic table using ui-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Have a look at the following code:

```
1.
<th ui-if="testBool">Test</th>
```

Problem with this snippet is that  gets generated and the ui-if only includes or excludes the value test but not the whole table header.

```
2.
<div ui-if="testBool">
     <th>Test</th>
</div>
```

This always shows the div nevertheless the value of testBool.

So is it possible to dynamically include th/tr's in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular already has a directive `ngIf` for this. The element on which `ng-if` is placed only gets rendered if ngIf holds true else it does not.

```
<th ng-if="testBool">Test</th>
```

You should be using atleast version 1.1.5 for this.

Comment: yes, but your code will generate <th></th> if testBool is false. I would like to know if it's possible to dynamically generate the whole <th> itself (my goal: nothing is generated when testBool is false).

Comment: Like I have already said if `ng-if` holds false, the element wont be rendered at all.

Comment: ha oke, can't test this since i'm stuck with v1.0.7. Thanks anyway

Comment: Oke I got it working; ui-if works exactly the same way. Just forgot to make an above header iffed also...